# Containerized App | Issues with TCP connection to container on specific port

Tags: docker, tcp

I created an linux application in `GO` consisting of a service `myappd` and a client `myapp`. I implemented a TCP based IPC on port `12345` between service and client hence the client could communicate with the service. If I run both on one machine, everything works fine.
Now I want to containerize the service. Therefore I created a Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:buster
COPY ./src/* /home/
RUN chmod 777 /home/myappd
ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash /home/myapp_entrypoint.sh
```

with the entrypoint script

```
echo create log locations
mkdir /var/log/myappd
chmod 744 /var/log/myappd
touch /var/log/myappd/myappd.log
chmod 744 /var/log/myappd/myappd.log
cd /home/
./myappd
```

And build the image with

```
docker build -t myappd:latest .
```

Running the container with

```
docker run --rm --name myappd -itd -p 127.0.0.1:12345:12345 myappd:latest
```

Afterwards I check, if the service is running and if the port is exposed to the localhost

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                        NAMES
4caf95e1bd72        myappd:latest      "/bin/sh -c '/bin/ba…"   6 minutes ago       Up 2 seconds        127.0.0.1:12345->12345/tcp   myappd
$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/init
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      520/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:12345         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10673/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1/init
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      520/sshd
```

It is looking good for me. But when I start the client on localhost, the dial on port `12345` succeeds but each request on the port `12345` is responsed instantly with `EOF` and without any content. If I run the service locally the IPC can be reached on the port `12345` as expected

```
$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/init
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      520/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:12345         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13184/./myappd
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1/init
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      520/sshd
```

Has anyone an idea why the IPC is working, when I run the service locally, but don't work if I run the service in a container?

Comment: What IP address is the server process listening on (can you show the `Listen()` call in your code)?  If it's listening on 127.0.0.1 it won't be accessible from outside its container.

Comment: Yes, it is listening on localhost. It is a good idea. The port act as local within the host but not in the container. From the container point of view the request comes from external. Good point. I will check

Comment: Changing the IPC server component of my app to listen to requests from all clients, solving the issue. Thanks a lot @DavidMaze, maybe you could formulate your comment as an answer so I could accept it?